# Do I have detect a different sides of the object as a single object or a different objects?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, object-detection

Do I have detect a different sides of the object as a single object or a different objects?

For example, I want to detect a cars using one of Region-based - Convolution Deep Neural Network - approach:

- Faster R-CNN: https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn
- Yolo darknet: https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet
- SSD: Single Shot MultiBox Detector: https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd

I want to detect a car from any side. And I am not interested which side I see.

[image]

All of 3 sides of the car look very different - as different dissimilar objects. Will this improve the detection, if I will detect each of the 3 sides as 3 different objects?

Or the last some fully connected layers completely solves this problem in CNNs?

- [GoogLeNet](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_googlenet/deploy.prototxt) - 1 fully connected layer
- [ResNet-152](https://github.com/KaimingHe/deep-residual-networks/blob/master/prototxt/ResNet-152-deploy.prototxt) - 1 fully connected layer
- [VGG16](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jimmie33/509111f8a00a9ece2c3d5dde6a750129/raw/d7299d1e4e3b7e11bdda4c42c9c88a9fd59f3301/deploy.prototxt) - 3 fully connected layers

And how many fully connected layers and neurons in each must be for detection of 3 sides of each of 20 objects?

Comment: in your training data, the car is annotated differently for each side?

Comment: @Shai Yes. For the same images I have both annotations (2 files): differently for each side and the same for each side.

Comment: If you have the annotations I would train each view as a different class.

Comment: @Shai If I will train each view as different class instead of the same class, then how will this improve the quality of detection (approximately in percent): for a few percents or a few tens of percents?

Comment: I have no way of estimating this. I guess you'll have to give it a try

Comment: For Faster RCNN, it does not take advantage of pose annotations.